# calculating total using angularjs and webforms usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms, user-controls, dynamic-usercontrols

Im new to using angularjs with webforms.

i am using asp.net 4.0 webforms project.  It have a usercontrol(uc.ascx) with a textbox and I dynamically multiple of the usercontrols on a page(Default.aspx)..on this aspx page i have a text box which should display the sum of the values in the textboxes of the dynamically added usercontrol..

can some one help me on how i can achieve this?

I researched all over the internet but could find a proper tutorial that works with usercontrols and angularjs

Comment: can you please post an SSCCE...?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think your are looking into the wrong direction angularJs isn't similar to [knockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) probably both of them have double binding, but definitely they are very different.

Angular is a Single page application that's built mostly for CRUD's applications, the typical architecture is to use a restFul web service behind angular (which is going to be your front end) and they communicate using JSON as the communitacion format, been that said, I'd suggest to move on ASP.NET web API and angular

this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VB81CLDtiI) could be helpful for you to get the whole picture.

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately i don't have an specific example for your scenario but I've found a couple of articles that may help you on your journey.

A good [example](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=933) of how to use knockout.js and asp.net definetelly you can look at it and take that as a good source for learn it and apply it to your case.

This is another [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153735/Using-KnockoutJS-in-your-ASP-NET-applications) using a usercontrol with knockoutjs

take a look to this [gibhub](https://github.com/MarlabsInc/webapi-angularjs-spa) repo with and example of the proposed architecture

Comment: can knockoutJS be used with asp.net to achieve the above said scenario?

Comment: do u have any example using the webapi and angular for this scenario... Thanks!?